# There is no GameScene.swift file in Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, sprite-kit

I'm learning to make games and all the tutorials and books have `GameScene.swift` file, but the new version of Xcode(6.3.1) doesn't have that file, as well as `GameScene.sks`

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: How did you create the app?  Did you use the `iOS > Application > Game`  Xcode project template?

Answer (score 2):

You probably chose SpriteScene instead of SpriteKit which is the 2D template for gaming that most videos on youtube and books use. SpriteScene is the 3D gaming template and is more advanced. 
[Go here for more info.](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ios-8-for/9780133965315/ch06lev2sec3.html)

Go: *create a new project > game > Game technology = sprite kit* - to get the 2d template.